# CSS Issue with Chrome - Navigation element bump

Tags: css, google-chrome, navigation, positioning

Working on an academic mock-up for a class. It's a simple reproduction of an existing company's webpage using only HTML and CSS. Everything was working perfectly in all browsers last week. I opened it yesterday to check it before submission and there's a problem.

In Chrome only, the last element of my navbar is being bumped straight down 19px.

The page. [link](http://webdev2.kennesaw.edu/IS3760/Section1/jbyford/capstone/index.html)
The css. [link](http://webdev2.kennesaw.edu/IS3760/Section1/jbyford/capstone/css/stylesheet.css)

The relevant css.

```
#navbar {
    position:absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 115px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height: 45px;
    background:url(../images/navbar_section.png) repeat-x;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
    -moz-box-shadow:    0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
    box-shadow:         0px 2px 2px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.27);
}
#navmenu {
    float:left;
    left:50%;
    position:relative;
    width:964px;
}
#navmenu ul, li {
    display: inline;
}
#navmenu li a {
    font-size:1em;
    float: left;
    color: white;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-left:2px groove #008dcb;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:45px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    right:50%;
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    width:138px;
}
#navmenu li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background:url(../images/navbar_visited.png);
}
#navmenu li:last-child a {
    border-right:2px groove #008dcb;
}
```

The relevant html.

```
<div id="navbar">
  <div id="navmenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">SHOP</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">WHY ALLTEL</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">PLANS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">APPS & MORE</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">CAREERS</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">EMPLOYEES</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div><!--end of navmenu-->
</div><!--end of navbar-->
```

I know it may be a bit confusing, if you look at the css file, to see navmenu and navmenu2, but just focus on navmenu, as the second is a different style that I haven't implemented.

I've tried removing the width elements with no change in the error.
I've tried copying the above code only into a fresh html document. Same error.

I'm at a complete loss. Please help!

Comment: *facepalm* I could have sworn I had already tried it, but I put in a padding reset into the ul. Problem solved. Sorry for wasting your time! I would set this to answered, but I can't because I'm a new user.

Comment: You can answer your own question and then select the answer as the right answer :)

Comment: In 7 hours I can lo. Says I can't answer my own since my rep is below 10.

Answer (score 0):

Clear padding. This is post just so there's a listed, recognized solution to this question.